# An interesting problem on arithmetic progression and maxima-minima

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

Came across this problem in national based examination.

**$a,b,c,d,e$ are natural numbers in AP.**

Now it is given that $a+b+c+d+e$=**cube of an *integer***

And $b+c+d$ = ***square of an integer***

The question asks us to find the **least number of digits** of **c**

Now here his my approach:

Let $a,b,c,d,e$ be denoted as $x-2,x-1,x,x+1,x+2$ respectively.

The $a+b+c+d+e=5x$

$b+c+d=3x$;

Then we can write
$5x=a^3$ and $3x=b^2$(As the question suggests that the integers may not be same)

After that i could not proceed..

Comment: do you know that $a,b,c,d,e$ are an A.P **of distance $1$**?

Comment: i think it will be better to replace 1  with some variable like y

Comment: they  will cancel out each other

Comment: make sense right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to solve $5Y^2=3X^3$. Assume $Y=3^{p}5^{q}$ and $X=3^{r}5^{s}$, so $2p=3r+1$ & $2q+1=3s$ ... The smallest values give $p=2$, $r=1$, $q=1,s=1$ which gives $Y=45$ and $X=15$.

This gives the central term in the AP is  $\color{red}{675}$. So the least number of digits is $\color{blue}{3}$.

Comment: Oh nooo.I was so close!